Grouping Json with same value of a key and rename keys with Jolt
This is a continuation of question asked in Grouping Json with same value of a key with Jolt
I want to do following changes in output JSON with JOLT. Could you please help on getting the desired JSON output. Thank you.

Add "StartTime" for each object in output json
Rename istance_3 and distance_4 into X_Z_distance and Y_Z_distance
Round Temp_1 value into 2 decimal points

Input JSON:
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "03.04.2023",
      "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
      "SessionData": [
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "0.36",
          "DataType": "distance_1"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "11.0",
          "DataType": "distance_2"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "2231",
          "DataType": "distance_3"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "0.04",
          "DataType": "distance_4"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "58.82",
          "DataType": "distance_5"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "0.00",
          "DataType": "distance_1"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "9.8",
          "DataType": "distance_2"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "2206",
          "DataType": "distance_3"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "0.00",
          "DataType": "distance_4"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "58.28",
          "DataType": "distance_5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]

Expected Output JSON:

[
  {
    "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
    "distance_1": "0.36",
    "LocationX": "36.282466",
    "LocationY": "-5.298164",
    "distance_2": "11.0",
    "X_Z_distance": "2231",
    "Y_Z_distance": "0.04",
    "Temp_1": 2189,
    "Distance_Type": "D",
    "Distance_Length": "M"
  },
  {
    "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
    "distance_1": "0.00",
    "LocationX": "36.278355",
    "LocationY": "-5.290660",
    "distance_2": "9.8",
    "X_Z_distance": "2206",
    "Y_Z_distance": "0.00",
    "Temp_1": 2164,
    "Distance_Type": "D",
    "Distance_Length": "M"
  }
]

JOLT:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "Location*": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).&",
              "@DataValue": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).@DataType"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Temp_1": "=doubleSum(@(1,distance_3),-42)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Distance_Length": "M",
          "Distance_Type": "D"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "distance_5": ""
      }
    }
  }
]


You can go on using the previous grouping technique as in the following transformation :
[
  { // you can pull all the expected attributes as some of them are arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "@2,StartTime": "@1,LocationX.@1,LocationY.StartTime",
              "Location*": "@1,LocationX.@1,LocationY.&",
              "@DataValue": "@1,LocationX.@1,LocationY.@DataType", // match the values of the attributes as a whole
              "#D": "@1,LocationX.@1,LocationY.Distance_Type",
              "#M": "@1,LocationX.@1,LocationY.Distance_Length"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "distance_5?": null, // prepare this attribute to be removed
          "Temp_1": "=intSum(@(1,distance_3),-42)" // expected result attribute is an integer
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // rename distance_3 and _4 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2_&1.&",
          "distance_3": "&2_&1.X_Z_distance",
          "distance_4": "&2_&1.Y_Z_distance",
          "distance_5": { "": "" } // reove this attribute
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only the first elements from the arrays
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // derive an array of objects without a key
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]


Anytime @casper ! That's just similr to this : https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#bucketToPrefixSoup the literal on the right-hand-side replaces the key of the respective attribute. Btw, &2 and &1 are used for distinction of the objects by key values from upper levels (in this case two of them needed)

Thank you, Barbaros Özhan. If I want to convert distance_2 value into decimal (from string value), how I can do it. e.g.: "distance_2" : "11.0" --> "distance_2" : 11.0

@casper just add "distance_2": "=toDouble" into the modify specification.

Your initial JOLT specification didn't properly reference the StartTime field at the correct level. You were attempting to access it at level *, but it should have been at level "0". did not include renaming distance_3 and distance_4 to X_Z_distance and Y_Z_distance respectively.
Incorrect Modification of Temp_1 and your JOLT spec lacked setting default values for Distance-length and distance-type.
also I removed the distance_5, your JOLT spec didn't include the removal of the distance_5 key as specified in the desired output.
here is the edited JOLT;
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": {
          "StartTime": "[&1].StartTime",
          "SessionData": {
            "*": {
              "LocationX": "[&2].LocationX",
              "LocationY": "[&2].LocationY",
              "DataValue": {
                "distance_1": "[&3].distance_1",
                "distance_2": "[&3].distance_2",
                "distance_3": "[&3].X_Z_distance",
                "distance_4": "[&3].Y_Z_distance",
                "*": {
                  "@": "[&3].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "X_Z_distance": "=toInteger",
        "Y_Z_distance": "=toInteger",
        "distance_3": "=toDecimal",
        "Temp_1": "=toInteger(@(1,distance_3) * 100)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Distance_Length": "M",
        "Distance_Type": "D"
      }
    }
  }
]


Thank you for your effort, small places need to modify I think, since Start time not repeated in every block and seems this is not group from LocationX and LocationY. Meantime Temp_1 gives an error. Could you please help to resolve

Also, we need to address the fact that the grouping is not based on LocationX and LocationY;
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "StartTime": "[&2].StartTime",
          "SessionData": {
            "*": {
              "LocationX": "[&3].LocationX",
              "LocationY": "[&3].LocationY",
              "DataValue": {
                "distance_1": "[&4].distance_1",
                "distance_2": "[&4].distance_2",
                "distance_3": "[&4].X_Z_distance",
                "distance_4": "[&4].Y_Z_distance",
                "*": {
                  "@": "[&4].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "X_Z_distance": "=toInteger",
        "Y_Z_distance": "=toInteger",
        "distance_3": "=toDecimal",
        "Temp_1": "=divide(@(1,distance_3), 100)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Distance_Length": "M",
        "Distance_Type": "D"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "SessionData": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

Added StartTime to each object at the correct level, and corrected the calculation for Temp-1 to divide distance_3 by 100 to round it to two decimal places. removed the Sessiondata key and its nested objects as they are no longer needed in the final output. also Ensured that default values are set for distance-Length and fistance_type. good luck.
